# Using 'has_many' relation in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am reading *Agile Web Development with Rails*. They have used the syntax:

`item = cart.line_items.build(product_id: product_id)`

My questions are:

1. What exactly is happening in the above statement? Which parts of the program are called? I couldnt find the detailed explanation.
2. why use build and then save instead of simply create?

Comment: Which action is this line appearing in? some_controller#new?

Comment: What do you mean, "which parts of the program are called"? Precisely the ones shown. Are you asking where `build` comes from?

Comment: By which part I meant the controller,model etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above line creates a new line_item associated with the cart and is initialized with a product_id.  Build is essentially a nice bit of DSL that lets you leverage already existing relationships for creating new objects.  It is just utilizing the `has_many: :line_items` relation in the cart and the standard Object.new

The advantage to this approach is that you get the association with the cart for free instead of doing:

```
line_item = LineIten.new
line_item.cart = cart
line_item.product_id = product_id
```

Answer (score 1):

The `has_many :association_name` method, when called in a model definition, creates several methods, one of which is the `.association_name` method, which makes a SQL query selecting all objects in that association.

To learn more about this, go to your terminal, type `rails c`, and you can start playing around with how this works.

Answer (score 1):

Check the documentation to see how many *auto-generated methods* are injected into the Object when you define a `has_many` relationship:

- [has_many documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many)

Among all of them it is the `collection.build`.

1) This method is just a helper so you only need to write one line for something that otherwise would need more than one.

2) Not special reason, depends on the context, sometimes you only want to initialize the object and not save it yet. If you want to save the object just after initialization use the other *auto-generated method* `collection.create!`